# extract "all" numerics from text string

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column

I have a Sharepoint Online list with a text field for a contact called Mobile Phone...
I want to extract the numerics only...

```
(111) 222-3333 would be 1112223333
+99 111-222-3333 would be 991112223333
111-222-3333 would be 1112223333
111 222 3333 would be 1112223333
```

I was expecting to be able to do this with a calculated column, but it's not as obvious as I thought. Ultimately our dialing system needs a numerics only version of the value (no special characters or spacing). I have seen similar questions answered here but not this exact need. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it is possible using a calculated column since the text field values are not in the same format.

I’ve also tried using Flow and split() function, similar to this [thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Split-Extract-names-from-a-delimiter-string-in-Flow/td-p/183773), yet it fails because it cannot identify different separators in the strings.

Consider using custom code to achieve this requirement, for example, JavaScript.

Here is a reference for you: 
[How to Get Numbers from a String in JavaScript.](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-get-numbers-from-a-string-in-javascript.htm)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this for awhile...I decided to do the following...

=CONCATENATE(IF(ISERR(MID([Mobile Number],1,1)*1),"",MID([Mobile Number],1,1)),IF(ISERR(MID([Mobile Number],2,1)*1),"",MID([Mobile Number],2,1)),IF(ISERR(MID([Mobile Number],3,1)*1),"",MID([Mobile Number],3,1)),IF(ISERR(MID([Mobile Number],4,1)*1),"",MID([Mobile Number],4,1)),IF(ISERR(MID([Mobile Number],5,1)*1),"",MID([Mobile Number],5,1)),IF(ISERR(MID([Mobile Number],6,1)*1),"",MID([Mobile Number],6,1)),
etc....keep going for however many characters you think you need to handle.
))

It works in so much that I get back the desired answers but it's not very flexible with the variable length. I go up to 23 characters in my code but the good news is I get back..